# How to map over a Dataset that holds a map in spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Dataset in spark with one column, This column is a Map[String, Any]. I would like to map over the Dataset, row by row and then map over the Map column, key by key, manipluate the value of each key and produce a new Dataset of the same type as the previous with the new data.

for example:

```
case class Data(column: Map[String, Any])
val ds: Dataset[Data] = Seq(Data(Map(("name","Andy"),("address","Street Name 1"))),Data(Map(("name","John"),("city","NYC")))).toDS()
```

And I want to add "+" at the end of each value, so the result would be a Dataset of type Data, as follows:

```
name -> Andy +, address -> Street Name 1 +
name -> John +, city -> NYC +
```

thanks
Nir

Comment: Aren't you getting `No Encoder found for Any`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val result =
  ds.map(data =>
    Data(data.column.map { case (key, value) => (key -> s"$value +") }
  )
```

or

```
val result = 
  ds.map(
    data => data.copy(column = data.column.map { case (key, value) => (key -> s"$value +") }
  )
```